# Which data or How to bind data in this situation (in Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm studying recyclerview adapter.
I don't know which data to bind in the empty space.
I'm guessing the mainImageView should be in the blank, but how do you bind it over?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnFAr.png)

And here is my code

`class GridRecyclerAdapter(
private val contentDTOs: ArrayList
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GridRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val width = parent.context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels / 3
    val mainImageView = ImageView(parent.context)
    mainImageView.layoutParams = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(width, width)
    return CustomViewHolder.from(parent)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(contentDTOs)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return contentDTOs.size
}

class CustomViewHolder private constructor(holder: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(holder) {
    fun bind(contentDTOs: ArrayList<ContentDTO>) {
        val context = itemView.context
        Glide.with(context).load(contentDTOs[adapterPosition].imageUrl)
            .apply(RequestOptions().centerCrop())
            .into()
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): CustomViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_grid, parent, false)
            return CustomViewHolder(view)
        }
    }
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide an `image` view reference that you are creating to glide builder.

```
class GridRecyclerAdapter(private val contentDTOs: ArrayList<ContentDTO>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GridRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        return CustomViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(contentDTOs)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return contentDTOs.size
    }

    class CustomViewHolder constructor(holder: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(holder) {
        val context = itemView.context
        val mainImageView = ImageView(context)
        var width: Int = context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels / 3
        fun bind(contentDTOs: ArrayList<String>) {
            mainImageView.layoutParams = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(width, width)
            Glide.with(context).load(contentDTOs[adapterPosition].imageUrl)
                    .apply(RequestOptions().centerCrop())
                    .into(mainImageView)
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): CustomViewHolder {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_grid, parent, false)
                return CustomViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }
}
```